# Multiple iterations over different arguments in a tuple (python)

Tags: python

I wrote the following code that iterates over multiple augments in a tuple.

```
def div (*tup):
    return [x/10 for x in tup]

>>> print div(100,50,30)
[10, 5, 3]
```

I would like my output to appear as three separate lists within a list:

```
[[10], [5], [3]]
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just make your return-statement like this:

```
return [[x/10] for x in tup]
```

Sample:

```
>>> def div(*tup):
...     return [[x/10] for x in tup]
...
>>> div(100,50,30)
[[10], [5], [3]]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response iCodez.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def div (*tup):
...     return [[x/10] for x in tup]
... 
>>> print div(100,50,30)
[[10], [5], [3]]
```